# Android - AlertDialog animation no longer working

Tags: android, animation, android-alertdialog

I had it working but now it isn't. There is nothing in logcat about it.

style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="DialogSlideAnim" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/push_right_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/push_right_out</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Java

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit??? Your progress will be saved.")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {

            }
        })
    .setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
                dialog.cancel();
                finish();
            }
        });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.hide();
alert.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogSlideAnim;
alert.show();
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with this code? Everything was working prior to me doing additional coding...and I have about 12 alertboxes on my activity.

Comment: what was the additional coding?

Comment: Are you saying it does not work after the animations?

Comment: So if you take out the last from second line what does it do?

Comment: when i implemented it, it worked...then i corrected some other code...now it is broken

Comment: that line is where i am setting the animations to the alertdialog

Comment: it was all database work...nothing with the ui